# url variable is set after rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+blog/index\.php\?c=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ blog/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([\w-]+)?$ blog/index.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the above works fine
now I ned a rule if there is no `c` variable - just `index.php`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+blog/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

**php**

```
if(isset($_GET['c'])){$cat = $_GET['c'];}
var_dump($cat); // empty string
```

I don't want the `c` variable to be set in the second case
what is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules for uris which have only index.php in it.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(blog)/index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/index.php? [L,R=301,NE,NC] 

##Rules for uris which have c variable added in it.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(blog)/index\.php\?c=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  %1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Rules for non-existent pages.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(blog)/([\w-]+)/?$  $1/index.php?c=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

***OR*** Above Rules sets do redirection to index.php for without query string URLs, in case you don't want to perform redirection then please try following rules, make sure either use above or following rules only one at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules for uris which have only index.php in it.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(blog)/index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/index.php? [L,NC] 

##Rules for uris which have c variable added in it.    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(blog)/index\.php\?c=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Rules for non-existent pages.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(blog)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/index.php?c=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: cache cleared. In both cases - doesn't work. First case - If I write `index.php in url` - there is no redirection. Second case - without `index.php` in url - `c` variable is still there

Comment: @qadenza, sure, I have edited my rules now. Kindly do check them once and let me know how it goes then, cheers. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: second case - the same result. first case - seems redirection works but there is still `c` variable. If  helps - here is the page - `https://abuena.net/blog/index.php` thanks a lot for your efforts

Comment: @qadenza, Sorry I am trying my best here, I have edited my rules now, could you please do test them once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: first case - redirection works, and that's enough. You're a real hero. FYI - the second case - url remains with `index.php` but doesn't matter - solved